# Import of new vertex from external json file

Tags: java, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

Is this code only import the vertex in json or it imports the vertex & add it to graph

`graph.io(GraphSONIo.build()).reader().create().readVertex(new FileInputStream("/tmp/Vertex.json"),null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only imports the vertex but does not adds it to graph as `readVertex` method signature is like this

```
Vertex readVertex(InputStream inputStream, Function<Attachable<Vertex>, Vertex> vertexAttachMethod)
```

so you need to use `graph` object to give as source to `Function<Attachable<Vertex>, Vertex> vertexAttachMethod` so it will read and add to your graph.